# Vector space under the real numbers problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

If E is a vector space under the real numbers, with addition and multiplication defined as:
$$ u\boxplus v = u+(-v); \space a \boxdot u = (-a)u$$ $$ a,b \in \mathbb{R}; \space u,v \in E $$
How can I prove the multiplication distributive axioms:
$$a \boxdot (u\boxplus v) = a\boxdot u \boxplus a \boxdot v$$ $$(a+b)\boxdot u = a\boxdot u  \boxplus b \boxdot u$$

Comment: Don't you want to prove $a \boxdot (u \boxplus v)=a \boxdot u \boxplus a \boxdot v$ and $(a \boxplus b) \boxdot v= a \boxdot v \boxplus b \boxdot v$?

Comment: Corrected the post, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must prove the distributive axioms for the operations defined, i. e., you must show that

$$a\boxdot(u\oplus v) =a\boxdot u\boxplus a\boxdot v$$
which is distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to **vector addition** and
$$(a+ b)\boxdot u =a\boxdot u\boxplus b\boxdot u$$
which is distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to **field addition** .

The proof must come from the definition:

$$a\boxdot(u\boxplus v) = a\boxdot(u-v) = -a(u-v) = -au + av =(-au)\boxplus(-av)= (a\boxdot u)\boxplus (a\boxdot v),  $$
and
$$ (a+ b)\boxdot u = (-a -b)u = -au+(-bu)=-au\boxplus (bu)=(a\boxdot u)\boxplus (-b\boxdot u). $$

So, the second distributivity rule doesn't apply.

Comment: Thank you, this makes it clear for me!

Answer (score 0):

Now $$a \boxdot (u \boxplus v)= (-a)(u +(-v))=((-a)u)+(-((-a)v))=\\
=(a\boxdot u) + (- (a \boxdot v))=(a\boxdot u) \boxplus (a \boxdot v)$$

and similar for the other proof.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!